# Powershell, pass a variable from a switch within a function to the rest o

Tags: function, powershell, switch-statement, do-while

Summary:
I am assigning a variable from within a switch that is within a do/while loop that is within a function; and I want to be able to access this variable from outside this function (within the same script).

Details:
The script has a do/while loop that prints the variable value (or prints a string if the variable has no value) to the screen and gives a couple options.  One option is to re-assign the variable.  If you chose this option you go into a function and a do/while loop with multiple ways to assign a value to this variable which is actually performed by a switch.  The switch assigns the variable (I have confirmed this variable is assigned the proper value from within the switch).  Once this is done the function is exited and you go back to the initial do/while loop (outside the function) and the variable (or string) that is supposed to be printed is now blank.

There is an If statement to check if the variable is empty or not `IF($Var -eq "") {Write-Host "Some String}` and after this process happens the string is not deplayed...as if the variable is assigned, but there is still nothing printed to the screen using  `Write-Host "$Var`

I have tried `Return $Var` from within the switch
I have tried scoping the variable globally `$Global:Var="some value"`
I have tried using "set-variable" from within the switch.

Here is an example of what I have:

```
Do {
    $exitloop = $False

    If($var -eq "") {
        Write-Host " - No Directory Set - "
    }
    Else {
        Write-Host "$var"
    }

    Write-Host "1 Continue"
    Write-Host "2 Change Directory"
    Write-Host "3 exit"

    $UserInput = Read-Host ""

    Switch($UserInput) {
        1 {
            Some logic we don't care aout
        }
        2 {
            Get_Directory
        }
        3 {
            some logic we don'e care about
        }
    }

}
While ($exitloop = $False)

Function Get_Directory {
    Do {
        $exitloop2 = $False
        clear-Host
        Write-Host "1 - some option"
        Write-Host "2 - some option"
        Write-Host "3 - set variable"

        $UserInput2 = Read-Host ""

        Switch($UserInput2) {
            1{
                Some logic we don't care about
            }
            2{
                Some logic we don't care about
            }
            3{
                Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
                $FolderBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
                [void]$FolderBrowser.ShowDialog()

                If($FolderBrowser.SelectedPath -eq "") {
                    $UserInput2=$Null
                    Clear-Host
                    Write-Host "No folder selected, returning to main menu..."
                    Start-Sleep -s 2
                    Exit
                }
                Else{
                    $Global:Var=$FolderBrowser.SelectedPath
                    $exitloop2 = $False
                    Return
                }
            }
        }
    }
    While($exitloop2 = $False)
}
```

As you can see, after the function runs, you should be taken back to the initial do/while loop and $var should be updated...but it is not.

Please let me know if you have any ideas

Comment: Of course you shouldn't post your whole code. But at least a [MCRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). E. g. a function with your "switch" that contains a loop that prints your variable. Should be done in less than 10 lines, shouldn't it?

Comment: Updated with example code

Answer (score 0):

Sorry all, after some fumbling around answered my own question.  I did 2 things and either 1 or both fixed it.

I had to remove the $exitloop2 = $True line and use the return $var line to pass the variable.

(or it could be that the first time I used the return $var line that I didn't save that change...which would be why it didn't work the first time I tested that approach.